# What does だけ mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

I'll start off with the line itself:

> 親公認で付き合えるこの状況だけで、奇跡と思わなくっちゃいけない。

The line seems simple enough. I know だけ has a few more meanings than just "only"  but none of those appear to fit here either and I get the feeling "only" is close to what's intended, but not not quite right. Here my literal, word-for-word translation: "In only this situation that I can go out with him/her with parental authorization, I must think it a miracle." It's ugly but I think it makes sense, save for "in only this situation". It's plain my understanding of that is wrong. How should I be interpreting だけ here?

Comment: Did it actually say 奇跡を instead of 奇跡と?

Comment: It did actually say 奇跡を I believe. I will double check when I get a chance.

Comment: Whoops, never mind. It did indeed say 奇跡と. My bad, tried to write it from memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「[親公認]{おやこうにん}で[付]{つ}き[合]{あ}えるこの[状況]{じょうきょう}**だけで**、[奇跡]{きせき}と[思]{おも}わなくっちゃいけない。」

「だけで」＝「だけでも」 in this context.

It means "***even just***", expressing the fact that a seemingly bare minimal condition would actually look quite satisfactory if one tried to see it from another perspective.

> "Even just this situation where we can go out with our parents' permission, we would need to consider a miracle."

It implies that one should not hope for more too soon.

Comment: I am a native speaker and I think this answer is correct. Nicely put!

Answer (score 1):

With just [her?] parent's OK to go out, I could only think "miraculous [is life]"

So it could be translated as "with just ~Q" in this case.

Comment: That's a good way of thinking about it. Thanks.